# Recursive CTE SQL to return all decendants and ancestors

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Given this table ...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Data](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ParentId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Data] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and associated data...

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Data]([Id], [Name], [ParentId])
SELECT 1, N'George', 4 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, N'Amit', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, N'Chad', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, N'David', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, N'Tess', 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 6, N'Emma', 3
COMMIT;
RAISERROR (N'[dbo].[Data]: Insert Batch: 1.....Done!', 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
GO
```

Can you please provide me with 2 separate  CTE SQLs to return of of the descendants and ancestors for a given ID?

Comment: Your Google Fu is weak, Grasshopper.  Have you tried nothing?

Comment: As the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page says: "Don't ask about... Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)". There are plenty of answers on SO dealing with CTEs, recursion and hierarchies. Had you included a query that wasn't working and asked for help, I'd have helped. If you described a particular aspect of the problem, e.g. how to terminate the recursion, it would have shown some insight. But "please provide me with 2 separate CTE SQLs"? You've been here long enough to ask a better question than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get you going in the right direction:

```
with childcte as (
  select id, name, parentid
  from data
  where id = 2
  union all
  select d.id, d.name, d.parentid
  from data d
    join childcte on d.parentid = childcte.id 
), parentcte as (
  select id, name, parentid
  from data
  where id = 2
  union all
  select d.id, d.name, d.parentid
  from data d
    join parentcte on d.id  = parentcte.parentid 
  )
select *
from childcte
union 
select *
from parentcte;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d3459/3)

Answer (score 1):

Try this CTE. You need to union with your users table aswell. I am getting all the hierarchy related to the user that you are searching, and will get all the children.

The query will start from the roots, that is why the first piece of the querying has  **where ParentId = null** . The second is getting all the children of the roots, so on so fourth.

```
 declare @UserId int
 select @UserId = 1

WITH hierarchy (Id, ParentId) AS
(
      SELECT
            Id, ParentId
      FROM
            [dbo].[Data]
      WHERE 
            parentid IS NULL 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT
            u1.Id, u1.ParentId 
      FROM
             [dbo].[Data] u1  
      INNER JOIN hierarchy ON 
            u1.ParentId = hierarchy.Id 
)

select * From hierarchy where ParentId = @UserId;
```

Comment: What does [UsersTable] alias?